# Middleware function is executed multiple times rather than just once when using dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have this middleware:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('test');
  next();
});
```

and I have these dynamic routes:

```
app.get('/:path', (req, res, next) =>{
  var pages = serverCache.pages;
  for (let page of pages) {
    if(req.params.path === page.path){
      res.render('foo', {
        helpers:helpers
      });
      return;
    }//if
  }//for
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

When a page is loaded I would expect execution of `console.log('test')` only once. However it is executed many times. Actual output is:

```
test
test
test
test
...
```

It happens because it is executed for each iteration inside `for` loop. How do I execute it only when `if` statement criteria inside that loop is true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I misunderstood when would function be executed.

The reason why it was executed multiple times is because it executes itself for each route it checks. (For all middleware functions afterwards)

For it to execute only for my dynamic routes, I moved both of these function to the bottom.

```
app.get('static route')
app.post('static route')
app.use('static route')
app.use(); // moved it here
app.get('dynamic route')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `o(1 + count of pages verifying the condition)`.

The simplest way to verify what is happening under the hood is debug your nodejs app, it you can't just put some logs in between like below

```
app.get('/:path', (req, res, next) =>{
  console.log('Get/:path'); //NOTICE HERE
  var pages = serverCache.pages;
  for (let page of pages) {
    if(req.params.path === page.path){
      console.log('rendering foo'); //NOTICE HERE
      res.render('foo', {
        helpers:helpers
      });
      return;
    }//if
  }//for
  console.log('redirecting to /'); //NOTICE HERE
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Is it caused because of the iteration: `for ( let page of pages ) ... `  ?

Comment: if your page didn't send any response (no page of pages verifies the condition), it becomes `o(1 + 1)`.

Comment: yes each `res.render('foo', {
        helpers:helpers
      });` executed will log `test`.

Comment: I see but when that route is hit, it should only execute `res.render` once because it is nested inside `if` statement that can only be `true` if `page` is found, and `page.path` is unique in database, so it will be always once or zero. Why does it still execute the function? How do I prevent that?

Comment: I've updated my answer, kindly check it and let me know what it prints

Comment: I understand. It has nothing to do with loop actually. It will be executed for each function it needs to check. (Each route). I just moved middleware function after these routes and it works fine now.